# Is it possible to perform a graph traversal in a graph database in one atomic step?

Tags: transactions, neo4j, orientdb, graph-databases, arangodb

In a side project I am looking into graph based databases for storing trees.
Storing and reading them was not a big issue (not surprisingly), but now it seems I have run into a dead end.
The trees are to be stored and read by a web page, so both may happen at the same time. Now several storage processes don't interfere with each other as write transactions are a common feature.

If on the other hand a write transaction is committed while another process is traversing the nodes the result will be faulty.

For example let's say one person opens the web page with the tree, edits it and commits the changes. At the same time someone else opens the page so that it is being read from the database while the commit is happening.

In order to read the tree from the database I traverse the nodes depth first and build a json object from the results. So it sometimes happens that if a node was moved from one branch to another one it is read two times, because it was read at the old position and by the time the read process reaches the new position the commit has happened.

I am using OrientDB now and haven't found a solution yet. Both the Java API and Tinkerpop Gremlin perform traversals as single calls, so I don't see any reason to believe that the server would put a lock on the data. From what I read the same applies to ArrangoDb, and in Neo4j's documentation it explicitly says: "Data retrieved by traversals is not protected from modification by other transactions." (http://neo4j.com/docs/stable/transactions.html)

Is this a general problem with graph databases or am I using the database incorrectly?
In case of OrientDb I might try to use the SQL syntax, but I don't see any reason to believe that that would solve the problem.

Answer (score 2):

Speaking just of Neo4j here, cannot comment on others: a transaction can modify the graph while another transaction is traversing the same area. But there's a way to prevent that: grabbing explicit locks.

The [`Transaction`](http://neo4j.com/docs/stable/javadocs/org/neo4j/graphdb/Transaction.html) interface contains methods to grab a lock. If the transaction doing the traversal takes locks, it will prevents concurrent writes on those.

Cypher (the neo4j query language) doesn't have a way to explicitly grab locks. The recommended workaround is to set a fake property and remove it in the end - as a side effect we'll hold a lock:

```
MATCH (n:Person {name:'myself'})
SET n._fake = 1
WITH n
....  do more stuff
REMOVE n._fake
RETURN <whateverresult>
```

Comment: Interesting. So in order to create a read lock you instead cause a write lock on an entity that is unique to the node group you want to access. So in my case I would probably set some dummy value on a tree's root node just so that my read traversal is enclosed in a write transaction.

The only downside I see is that this doesn't allow concurrent reads either, right?
On second thought - as both OrientDB and ArangoDB feature MVCC, it should be enough to start a transaction and acquire such a "fake" write lock in the beginning and then just never commit the unnecessary changes. I'll check it out.